# Python & Matplotlib: How to pass dict to functions?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm making a custom plot configure function `plt_configure`, so I can combine label, legend and other plot options with one command.

For legend, I want to do something like:

```
plt_configure(legend={loc: 'best'})
# => plt.legend(loc='best')
plt_configure(legend=True)
# => plt.legend()
```

Then how should I define the function?

Now I define the function as this:

```
def plt_configure(xlabel='', ylabel='', legend=False):
    plt.xlabel(xlabel)
    plt.ylabel(ylabel)
    if legend:
        # if legend passed as options
            plt.legend(options)
```

or my function design is bad, what would be a good design to consider the above 2 case? 
            # else 
                plt.legend()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An empty dictionary will evaluate to `False`, a not empty one will evaluate to `True`. Therefore you can use `if legend` no matter if `legend` is a dict or a boolean.

Then you can test if `legend` is a dict, and pass it to `plt.legend`

```
def plt_configure(xlabel='', ylabel='', legend=False):
    plt.xlabel(xlabel)
    plt.ylabel(ylabel)
    if legend:
        if isinstance(legend, dict):
            plt.legend(**legend)
        else:
            plt.legend()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `None` instead in your keyword argument since legend would otherwise be a `dict` object (not a boolean instance) and then check if the legend is a dictionary instance:

```
def plt_configure(xlabel='', ylabel='', legend=None):
    plt.xlabel(xlabel)
    plt.ylabel(ylabel)
    if legend and isinstance(legend, dict):
        # get options then...
        plt.legend(options)
```

Answer (score 2):

Moses Koledoye's answer is fine, however if you want to pass additional options to legend, you'd want to pass them to your function, as well:

```
def plt_configure(xlabel, ylabel, legend, *args, **kwargs):
    plt.xlabel(xlabel)
    plt.ylabel(ylabel)
    if legend:
        plt.legend(*args, **kwargs)
```

this way you can pass arbitrary arguments and/or keywords to the legend function

Answer (score 1):

I join to early answers, but I think, checking for None have to be in function and you `legend` dict have to use as `kwargs`:

```
def plt_configure(xlabel='', ylabel='', legend=None):
    plt.xlabel(xlabel)
    plt.ylabel(ylabel)
    if not(legend is None): plt.legend(**legend)

...

plt_configure(xlabel='x', ylabel='y', legend={'loc': 'best','mode': 'expand'})
```